# SDK SOS version to use for App Android 8.1.0?

Tags: mobilesdk

We are a Salesforce customer on behalf of a large group in the banking industry, we opened a ticket with the salesforce support who guided our team in charge of the salesforce Mobile section.

For several days now, we have been experiencing an APP android crash for Android 8.1.0 smartphone users because of SOS SDK version 2.2.0. What updated version of the SOS SDK should be used to solve the problem? possible impacts on the updated version?, without the new verison impact app on iOS that works well.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

SOS is a different product than the Mobile SDK. You are post issues for SOS here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android